# Is there a word for a name based on something someone does?

Tags: names

Is there a word for a name or nickname based on something someone does, or a characteristic they have?

For example "Thumper"  (from Bambi) or "Crazy-Ed".

I am thinking of something that identifies this type of name.

Comment: There's "aptronym", which is a name that is amusingly well-suited to a person (e.g. Dr. Angst, a professor of psychology who focuses on anxiety), but that's not really suited to a nickname you give someone on purpose.

Comment: Perhaps *epithet*?

Comment: I think it IS "nickname". Definition: a usually descriptive name given instead of or in addition to the one belonging to a person, place, or thing (m-w.com)

Comment: A nickname doesn't have to be descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like greek roots: [aptonym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aptonym), [aptronym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aptronym), [euonym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/euonym)

Comment: That was the kind of thing I was looking for. Aptronym is pretty close, although maybe slightly more general than what I described.